# Is $a^p - a \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ technically a correct way of stating Fermat's Little Theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need it for a presentation and I do not want to have a technical mistake in it. I haven't seen it stated like that anywhere.

Comment: Well, you should add the quantifiers.  Like that you want this to hold for prime $p$ and all integers $a$.

Comment: Concerning not having seen the theorem stated that way, you just haven't looked widely enough. Section 5 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/eulerthm.pdf has three generalizations of Fermat's little theorem to congruences mod $m$ for $m \geq 2$ that are valid for *all* integers, unlike Euler's theorem. All three generalizations reduce to the congruence $a^p - a \equiv 0 \bmod p$ when $m = p$ is a prime number.

Comment: lulu's comment here is really important. You must state that $p$ is prime; omitting that would indeed be a technical mistake.

Comment: @Joffan it's also really important to say the congruence is true for all integers $a$. I once had a student tell me Fermat's little theorem says for every prime there is some integer $a$  such that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$.  Uh....

Comment: @KCd nice paper. I like the sneaky $a^m \equiv a^{m−\varphi(m)} \bmod m$. For myself I also like the idea of "saturation", which might be somewhat covered in the proof for the above, but essentially $s(m) = max_{p\mid m}\nu_p(m)$ and then $ \forall k\geq s(m): a^k \equiv a^{k+\varphi(m)} \bmod m$. Of course you could also vary this saturation threshold based on $a$.

Comment: For a little bit extra oomph you may include (as a teaser, don't necessarily waste time proving it though it follows easily from the so called Freshman's dream) that for Gaussian integers $a+bi$, $a,b\in\Bbb{Z}$, the rules will be a bit different:
$$(a+bi)^p\equiv a+bi\pmod p$$
whenever $p\equiv1\pmod4$ but
$$(a+bi)^p\equiv a-bi\pmod p$$ whenever $p\equiv-1\pmod4$. In other words, for half the primes you get the complex conjugate but for the other half there will be no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. If you still didn't see it somewhere, [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fermats-little-theorem/) is one that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a perfectly valid way to do it, for starters it is true.

If we know that $a^p-a \equiv 0 \bmod p$ for all $a$ then it is easy to show $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$ is true for $a\not\equiv 0 \bmod p$ (although I think you use the multiplicative inverse but I think proving those exist is easy).